# Which board should i select for "NodeMcu ESP32-S" in platformio?

Tags: esp32, platformio

I have recently switches to platformio and I seem not being able to find the correct board for my esp. In the arduino ide I used the esp32 dev module board and seemed to work fine, but i couldn't find that board in platfromio and even checked the platformio board registry(https://registry.platformio.org/platforms/platformio/espressif32/boards?p=1). I have tried various other boards but couldnt find one to match mine.

Comment: Use the [NodeMCU-32S](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/espressif32/nodemcu-32s.html) board.

Comment: I chose the NodeMCU32-s but now its showing this problem.                            Looking for upload port...
Auto-detected: COM4
Uploading .pio\build\nodemcu-32s\firmware.bin
esptool.py v3.3
Serial port COM4
Connecting......................................

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
*** [upload] Error 2. I have changed the baud rate to 9600 in the code and in the ini file.

Comment: Is COM4 the correct port?

Comment: Yes, I have checked on the devices of windows and even on arduino it shows com4